# Tried various solutions but header redirect still not working

Tags: php, redirect, header

The e-mail sends fine, but then it just stays on the blank `mail.php` page. There are no extra spaces, I added `ob_start` at the beginning and exit after the header. I tried looking at various different solutions but none of them seem to be working. I'm fairly new at php, is there something I missed?

Thank you!

```
<?php
ob_start();

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$number = check_input($_POST['inputNumber'], "Your Phone Number");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$date = check_input($_POST['inputDate'], "mm-dd-yyyy");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Someone has sent you an appointment request";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your appointment request form:

Name: $name
Number: $number
Email: $email
Date: $date

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: index.php');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: `ob_start()` shouldn't be needed here, but if you add error checking ( `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`)you'll likely find that you're sending something to the browser which negates the redirect.

Comment: @jay-blanchard I added that snippet of code to the end of the first php script but it's still a blank mail.php page

Comment: Add it right after the opening PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what happened but it just started working?

Comment: Are there 2 PHP scripts here? I see 2 PHP closing tags, but only one open tag.

Comment: The last four lines of the code are another script I believe?

Comment: I'm sorry but an error finally showed up 


"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /homepages/25/d566913414/htdocs/ramirezLCSW/appointment.php on line 39"

Comment: Then you have a semi-colon that shouldn't be where it is.